# array_diff return an empty array, is there any mistake in my codes?

Tags: php, arrays

i have problem, array_diff in this code didn't working and return empty array

```
for ($baris = 0; $baris < count($ala[0]); $baris++) {
    $satu[]= $ala[0][$baris];
    $dua[]= $ala[1][$baris];    
}

for ($baris=0; $baris < $jumlah ; $baris++) { 
    $satusatu[] = $ala[0][$baris];
    $duadua[] = $ala[1][$baris];     
}

$z = array_diff($satu, $satusatu);

print_r($z);
```

Comment: Please include your source arrays data ($ala)...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `count($ala[0]) ==  $jumlah` so the loops run the same iterations and you are doing the exact same assignment to the two arrays so there is no difference (empty array):

```
$satu[]= $ala[0][$baris];
//same as
$satusatu[] = $ala[0][$baris];
```

Answer (score 0):

array_diff ([see here](https://www.php.net/array_diff)) returns an empty array if the compared arrays are equal...

Answer (score 0):

First echo $satu and $satusatu before array_diff line.

This is how u need to debug

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire PHP code, then you are defining `$satu` inside your `for` loop, which means that - because of how variable scope works in PHP - `$satu` does not exist outside of the `for` loop. The same is true for `$satusatu`. Both of these arrays, when you attempt to reference them when calling `array_diff` are empty arrays since they have fallen out of scope. And so, when you call `array_diff` on these two arrays, the result will be that there is no difference between the two.

More information on variable scope in PHP can be [found here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) .